Error During 'Sugar Deploy' on Solana Devnet (Using Sugar V2)Cant finish deploy of my NFTs on Solana Devnet
I'm currently working on deploying an NFT collection on the Solana Devnet using Sugar V2. The sugar validate and sugar upload commands were completed successfully, indicating that my assets and metadata passed the initial checks and were uploaded without issues. However, when running sugar deploy, I'm encountering an error that prevents the deployment from finishing.
Details of the process:

Tools/Versions:

CLI: Sugar V2
Network: Solana Devnet



- Commands executed:

sugar validate – Passed with no issues.
sugar upload – Completed successfully.
sugar deploy – Error encountered (details below).

Error message:
[2/3]  Creating and setting the collection NFT for candy machine

 Error running command (re-run needed): Token Metadata Error: DataTypeMismatch: Data type mismatch

Troubleshooting steps already taken:

Double-checked the metadata structure to ensure it complies with Metaplex standards.
Verified that the assets uploaded to IPFS were accessible and correct.
Confirmed that my wallet has sufficient Devnet SOL balance for deployment.

Questions for the community:

Has anyone faced a similar error during the sugar deploy step using Sugar V2?
Are there common issues or pitfalls with deploying to the Devnet I might have overlooked?
Any advice or pointers on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!
I'm trying to mint a test collection to ensure everything works before deploying on the mainnet. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!
My files:
0.json - 09.json
{
  "name": "Golden Ape Meme #1",
  "symbol": "GAM",
  "description": "\u2728 The Legend of the Golden Ape \u2728\nBorn from the magic of a dying star, the Golden Ape shines with the light of a thousand sunsets, its fur glowing like molten gold and eyes full of ancient wisdom. \ud83d\udc35\u2728 Escaping the mystical forest, it leaps through the Veil of Time into Rainbowland, a digital Metaverse where art, culture, and magic collide. Here, the Golden Ape thrives, gracing neon streets and interacting with dreamers, a symbol of luxury, power, and mystery. Unlock the magic with a Golden Ape Meme Coin, a gift of boundless possibilities and hidden treasures. \u2728 Join the Legend. Own the Magic. \u2728",
  "image": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT6ARMBmgSP3zsBzRzdo6JhgqriPtu2KK17r4hv2KaR88",
  "attributes": [
    { "trait_type": "Hat", "value": "Crown" },
    { "trait_type": "Hair", "value": "Golden" },
    { "trait_type": "Fur", "value": "Shimmering Gold" },
    { "trait_type": "Eyes", "value": "Brown" },
    { "trait_type": "Glasses", "value": "None" },
    { "trait_type": "Beard", "value": "Clean-shaven" },
    { "trait_type": "Mustache", "value": "None" },
    { "trait_type": "Ears", "value": "Bare" },
    { "trait_type": "Neck", "value": "Smooth and Regal" },
    { "trait_type": "Expression", "value": "Regal Calm" },
    { "trait_type": "Background", "value": "Golden Aura" },
    { "trait_type": "Attire", "value": "Majestic Minimal" },
    { "trait_type": "Emotion", "value": "Peaceful Sovereignty" },
    { "trait_type": "Profession", "value": "King" },
    { "trait_type": "Accessories", "value": "Crown" },
    { "trait_type": "Rarity", "value": "Divine" }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmTGhTUV8scrP4VZnS1gQmX5vbamJ2cbEvtm4EJWC1P5JD",
        "type": "application/json"
      }
    ],
    "category": "image",
    "creators": [
      {
        "address": "Er211sqeJDA1Xsy4FfpoCqimL8aVvNnp6Afg2sE4j8qg",
        "share": 50
      },
      {
        "address": "6TxVeJwRWHpqW9H4oFkGn4hCXxi7Y3CYyYY8bVmQefP1",
        "share": 50
      }
    ]
  }
}

collection.json
{
  "name": "Golden Ape Meme",
  "symbol": "GAM",
  "uri": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmTGhTUV8scrP4VZnS1gQmX5vbamJ2cbEvtm4EJWC1P5JD",
  "creators": [
    {
      "address": "Er211sqeJDA1Xsy4FfpoCqimL8aVvNnp6Afg2sE4j8qg",
      "share": 50
    },
    {
      "address": "6TxVeJwRWHpqW9H4oFkGn4hCXxi7Y3CYyYY8bVmQefP1",
      "share": 50
    }
  ],
  "description": "A majestic collection showcasing golden-themed apes in luxurious attire, symbolizing opulence and unique artistry.",
  "image": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT6ARMBmgSP3zsBzRzdo6JhgqriPtu2KK17r4hv2KaR88",
  "properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmTGhTUV8scrP4VZnS1gQmX5vbamJ2cbEvtm4EJWC1P5JD",
        "type": "application/json"
      }
    ],
    "category": "image",
    "creators": [
      {
        "address": "Er211sqeJDA1Xsy4FfpoCqimL8aVvNnp6Afg2sE4j8qg",
        "share": 50
      },
      {
        "address": "6TxVeJwRWHpqW9H4oFkGn4hCXxi7Y3CYyYY8bVmQefP1",
        "share": 50
      }
    ]
  },
  "attributes": [
    { "trait_type": "Category", "value": "Meme" },
    { "trait_type": "Hat", "value": "Crown" },
    { "trait_type": "Hair", "value": "Golden" },
    { "trait_type": "Fur", "value": "Shimmering Gold" },
    { "trait_type": "Eyes", "value": "Brown" },
    { "trait_type": "Glasses", "value": "None" },
    { "trait_type": "Beard", "value": "Clean-shaven" },
    { "trait_type": "Mustache", "value": "None" },
    { "trait_type": "Ears", "value": "Bare" },
    { "trait_type": "Neck", "value": "Smooth and Regal" },
    { "trait_type": "Expression", "value": "Regal Calm" },
    { "trait_type": "Background", "value": "Golden Aura" },
    { "trait_type": "Attire", "value": "Majestic Minimal" },
    { "trait_type": "Emotion", "value": "Peaceful Sovereignty" },
    { "trait_type": "Profession", "value": "King" },
    { "trait_type": "Accessories", "value": "Crown" },
    { "trait_type": "Rarity", "value": "Divine" }
  ]
}

config.json
{
    "number": 10,
    "symbol": "GAM",
    "sellerFeeBasisPoints": 250,
    "isMutable": true,
    "isSequential": false,
    "ruleSet": null,
    "creators": [
        {
            "address": "Er211sqeJDA1Xsy4FfpoCqimL8aVvNnp6Afg2sE4j8qg",
            "share": 50
        },
        {
            "address": "6TxVeJwRWHpqW9H4oFkGn4hCXxi7Y3CYyYY8bVmQefP1",
            "share": 50
        }
    ],
    "price": 0.01,
    "uploadMethod": "bundlr",
    "awsS3Bucket": null,
    "retainAuthority": true,
    "awsConfig": null,
    "nftStorageAuthToken": null,
    "shdwStorageAccount": null,
    "pinataConfig": null,
    "hiddenSettings": null,
    "solTreasuryAccount": "Er211sqeJDA1Xsy4FfpoCqimL8aVvNnp6Afg2sE4j8qg",
    "splTokenAccount": null,
    "splToken": null,
    "guards": {
        "default": {
            "solPayment": {
                "value": 0.01,
                "destination": "Er211sqeJDA1Xsy4FfpoCqimL8aVvNnp6Afg2sE4j8qg"
            },
            "startDate": {
                "date": "2024-11-17T20:00:00Z"
            }
        }
    }
}

cache.json
{
  "program": {
    "candyMachine": "E2Fos9js2WRN9jC9GqVG1jLwSoiPAqxDxgRUze9Mib7T",
    "candyMachineCreator": "BEC7wdawCqvR8uTcqpBAwDTNFTxcsHTVpWzPLtuDhQ6K",
    "collectionMint": ""
  },
  "items": {
    "-1": {
      "name": "Golden Ape Meme Collection",
      "image_hash": "99faf4d263c5e4eb1b2d48bce689253a6594377dd2fdc3ccbe3f8a01bc151e76",
      "image_link": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT6ARMBmgSP3zsBzRzdo6JhgqriPtu2KK17r4hv2KaR88",
      "metadata_hash": "346183a049aa79c97c846530faabfdb6d1d6b46aba3e65e5cf9590a13f3f5b87",
      "metadata_link": "https://arweave.net/8uwUqRNtDP71moSXygsBBxSfmxrDUEuKFXV9YKcWojDS",
      "onChain": false
    },
    "0": {
      "name": "Golden Ape Meme #1",
      "image_hash": "1e8487c48a1fec5cb618af7a420fd0aac8c61a66b52fafa6aec875784e7ff0e9",
      "image_link": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT6ARMBmgSP3zsBzRzdo6JhgqriPtu2KK17r4hv2KaR88",
      "metadata_hash": "d6b453d1abcb012895a2d30ea34a76aaea8d38f7cabcea757343767a65cf8de6",
      "metadata_link": "https://arweave.net/5Wou5kHsEpj4MPL23ZpXpcyPMreBha7wggiDqJRcB6T8",
      "onChain": false
    },
    "1": {
      "name": "Golden Ape Meme #2",
      "image_hash": "0d777372e654f670a8254b7985aa6d9a273184c3829f36c0fb011833e01ab00b",
      "image_link": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT6ARMBmgSP3zsBzRzdo6JhgqriPtu2KK17r4hv2KaR88",
      "metadata_hash": "acb47d9e2c389749ffa8fadcb23cd7da7427e70ed270ba22730bdbdcb04f6719",
      "metadata_link": "https://arweave.net/DPojHumzcHb9gaZQJt2tB45ukAuTkNFuk7HquVMz5Hyq",
      "onChain": false
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "Golden Ape Meme #3",
      "image_hash": "7675a1a79c8730b0a7727da3c8f9c018d6b62a8727034ee915606e7e1a0ec053",
      "image_link": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT6ARMBmgSP3zsBzRzdo6JhgqriPtu2KK17r4hv2KaR88",
      "metadata_hash": "fde12fc7dda990317339535622f08aa1d1a339a44843b18cdeb22bb174df26b6",
      "metadata_link": "https://arweave.net/14Y3XJ8RnbPsCL7dmVrprLUXdc3HLCNZ8nevHQGPtiTg",
      "onChain": false
    },
    "3": {
      "name": "Golden Ape Meme #4",
      "image_hash": "e76de2e7de62313e74529dd674e7175beca72f01b0e702d748d2447d18b0f50a",
      "image_link": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT6ARMBmgSP3zsBzRzdo6JhgqriPtu2KK17r4hv2KaR88",
      "metadata_hash": "3b55d54522af71966055f8ee334782f0f8f7918d8097fea153e428ad8bb32445",
      "metadata_link": "https://arweave.net/44gfncUnyz11TbMuhHLVVkSxdgy3KPPGGpXnVwxRMC5m",
      "onChain": false
    },
    "4": {
      "name": "Golden Ape Meme #5",
      "image_hash": "68d347e2de1adf69fc3c09dc41af32bf57a0cb6ce0f9edf4aea450a1353e021a",
      "image_link": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT6ARMBmgSP3zsBzRzdo6JhgqriPtu2KK17r4hv2KaR88",
      "metadata_hash": "c134f2738754f1875354017ea6b7d16caf97eeed319c231570ea4fb138047db8",
      "metadata_link": "https://arweave.net/6K77ViHLMd9kj3PbuGYGvFGiwyGqEj3KopGjihDwQ2cB",
      "onChain": false
    },
    "5": {
      "name": "Golden Ape Meme #6",
      "image_hash": "c8fdb533c01213135b88d7dafa4ae703a38d2d52143d7e8fe116069477efcdc5",
      "image_link": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT6ARMBmgSP3zsBzRzdo6JhgqriPtu2KK17r4hv2KaR88",
      "metadata_hash": "c62c066753a330c1d3bdabe9a1d30713ee9e56f7a75935102ebf937c9704937a",
      "metadata_link": "https://arweave.net/45jacmQGSwTSvQC8yshbGqfk6mX7r21wV5Z9Lmgox2pf",
      "onChain": false
    },
    "6": {
      "name": "Golden Ape Meme #7",
      "image_hash": "448727a54c43ed6c08afe1db4c6cadb1d12c200182cb3ea2a55c012169a4e9a1",
      "image_link": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT6ARMBmgSP3zsBzRzdo6JhgqriPtu2KK17r4hv2KaR88",
      "metadata_hash": "a8198871305ad84e49740fcb0a71129224ccfdb60d0bcc722ed136110ea7f570",
      "metadata_link": "https://arweave.net/Sqhqz3bf5gegtsyAqGsk4tua4EMfHNhUi7drj1L2myx",
      "onChain": false
    },
    "7": {
      "name": "Golden Ape Meme #8",
      "image_hash": "24a09f6b722678792a593cd339ee492ee84bed45342fd33e02c1686eb0a91932",
      "image_link": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT6ARMBmgSP3zsBzRzdo6JhgqriPtu2KK17r4hv2KaR88",
      "metadata_hash": "2ef0dde7c0525c7c9442d0c79a4025ed642062fd8040b68d27bc9d67a4de288c",
      "metadata_link": "https://arweave.net/9V8inB5ryfCBUTkcKSCwQTNDWTz92is1HphoF67Jz9nw",
      "onChain": false
    },
    "8": {
      "name": "Golden Ape Meme #9",
      "image_hash": "ccbe18eadbb533c053baee81832fb89c4a0678e932d3364a7e9ead41edb505ff",
      "image_link": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT6ARMBmgSP3zsBzRzdo6JhgqriPtu2KK17r4hv2KaR88",
      "metadata_hash": "a71d711419408db21526b9a9b94a988df273123f78d70a70d0887706b8bd0f46",
      "metadata_link": "https://arweave.net/8sTHVJGLXFwFuxmn7n1cSQEPr5htbYLbeuZc9p7CgDYM",
      "onChain": false
    },
    "9": {
      "name": "Golden Ape #10",
      "image_hash": "4629364713a2f17b3db27b7c157f2b5488d661c1ebe69c8b9cddd87ce37bb9be",
      "image_link": "https://ivory-olympic-ferret-210.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT6ARMBmgSP3zsBzRzdo6JhgqriPtu2KK17r4hv2KaR88",
      "metadata_hash": "a5a531391edc12119b397de08585a11e5b59eaa93c942c0f764db47825d02f63",
      "metadata_link": "https://arweave.net/DK5dn2rB9wnsLnP7tjLcquMwsCucC8K3WVaSAEbxutZH",
      "onChain": false
    }
  }
}


This most likely is caused by an incorrect Sugar version. Make sure you are on the latest version that accounts for the new Token Metadata account sizes.

Make sure upgrade sugar to latest version, i fixed this mistake after upgrade 2.6.* to 2.7.* from source code

When I try upgrading to the latest version, I get an error stating that my macOS is x86, but an M1 or A-series chip is required.
